# How to update an element within an array which is in an array itself?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array['11'][] = [
   'One' => True,
   'Two' => False
];
```

How would I update the key-value of 'Two'? 
I've tried array_replace() with

```
$new_array['11'][] = [
   'Two' => True
];
```

But that does replaces the entire $array with $new_array. Meaning it'll become

```
$array['11'][] = [
    'Two' => False
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have a 3 dimensional array therefore you need to properly reference the value of the child element you want to update.

```
$array['11'][0]['Two'] = True;
```

This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function to do this, you need to loop over the array.

```
foreach ($array['11'] as &$subarray) {
    $subarray['Two'] = true;
}
```

The `&` makes `$subarray` a reference so modifying it updates the original array.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid a loop, I should have mentioned that. But @samsungcruiser answered the question perfectly. Appreciate the aid!

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a loop? What if there are multiple elements in the array?